# Host key verification failed bitbucket pipeline

Tags: deployment, bitbucket, devops, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Hi i have a problem configuring bitbucket pipeline with ssh login on my remote server.

The output of error is:
**ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Host key verification failed**

These are the steps i follow:

- generate private and public keys (without password) on my server using this command: *ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096*
- add base64 encoded private key under Repository Settings->Pipelines->Deployments->Staging environments
- push file "my_known_hosts" on the repository created with: *ssh-keyscan -t rsa myserverip > my_known_hosts*

I also tried to do another test:

- generate keys from Repository Settings
- copy public key to authorized_keys file on my remote server
- type the ip of my remote server in "Known hosts" click fetch and add
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
- chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

This is how i configure pipeline ssh connection

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to staging
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - echo "Deploying to staging environment"
          - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          - cat ./my_known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          - (umask  077 ; echo $SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
          - ssh $USER@$SERVER -p$PORT 'echo "connected to remote host as $USER"'
```

I'm trying all possible things but still can't connect.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This happen when you try to ssh the first time to the server, you can remove host checking by this option **StrictHostKeyChecking=no**, below is the complete command for your reference.

- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER -p$PORT 'echo "connected to remote host as $USER"'

PS: disabling host checking is not secure way to do, you can add server key to your ~/.ssh/known_host , run this command ssh-keyscan host1 , replace host1 to the host you want to connect.

Comment: Thank you it's works.
But i still do not understand why from bitbucket pipeline to my root machine on digital ocean i can connect without this parameter? Is put this parameter in the pipeline secure?

Comment: No its not, totally depends on how you are interacting with the server (if its private to private no issue go ahead), you can manually add the server in known host also to get rid of this error.
but if you really don't want to disable host checking , add server key to your ~/.ssh/known_host , run this command ssh-keyscan host1 , replace host1 to the host you want to connect.
Hit thumbs up if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i found the solution so i decide to write an article on dev.to https://dev.to/manuelbosi/bitbucket-pipelines-configure-ssh-keys-1l56